# How do protein-protein interaction databases work?

Tags: database, public-databases, proteomics, protein-protein-interaction

I am a student and just trying to gain a base level understanding of PPI databases and how to interpret their data.

For example, when inputing multiple genes into String, does it only give protein-protein interactions between those identified in my gene list? Or does it compare the input gene list to a background of your selected species? If it's the former, is it normal to only want protein-protein interactions between those in your input list?

Is there a resource/text where I can find more information about PPI databases? Any help in the right direction or where I can learn more would be appreciated.